# Postman how to send server SSL certificate client.crt

Tags: postman

I want to convert the following curl into a Postman script:

```
curl --cacert ca.crt --key client.key --cert client.crt "https://myurl"
```

All three SSL parts are required, i.e. client cert, client key AND server cert.

In Postman settings - certificates, I can set the CLIENT crt and the client KEY....but how do I set the server cert that is also required otherwise the request will fail.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this I converted ca.crt, client.key and client.crt into a .pfx file using this command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt -certfile CA.crt

This created a file called certificate.pfx

[You will be prompted whether you want to add a password for the file or not].

- Open Postman – click on the settings cog and then choose Settings
- Click on Certificates
- Click on ‘Add Certificate’ to the right of Client Certificates
- In the Host section set the url as required for your API
- In the PFX file section click on Select File and browse to certificate.pfx
- If you created a password for certificate.pfx - enter that in the Passphrase section
- Click on ‘Add’
- Close Settings
- You should now be able to send the request to the API and get a successful response